# Spring Data for NHibernate 5

Tags: c#, spring, nhibernate, spring-data, spring.net

Is there a Spring.NET solution for NHibernate 5.0? I have tried to update nhibernate 5, but it was not possible because spring data only supports nhibernate <=4. Can you help me?